# unix sed command to check if anything is replaced

Tags: unix, sed

I am basically using `sed -i 's:a:b:g' filename.txt` command to replace `a` with `b` in a file.
 Now I would like to know if there is any way i can know if the replacements are done(basically there were `a` 's in the file) after statement got executed.

Comment: don't know what you're asking. `sed -i 's:a:b:g' filename.txt` will do it's job perfectly.

Comment: basically i am looking for a scenario when there are no "a" 's in the file. Then nothing would be replaced right. I would like to know that there were no "a"'s. If i put in other terms can i know the no. of replacements which are done

Comment: `grep -c -i 'a' filename.txt` will return number of `a` (in fact line with `a`). You could ask before and after running sed if you want to know and skipping the call to sed if no occurence of `a` is find at first call

Answer (score 2):

Here is one method:

```
sed -i.bak 's:a:b:g' file && diff file file.bak
```

This creates a back-up file and then compare the backup with the new version.  Any line with changes will be displayed.

For OSX/BSD systems, you might need to leave a space between `-i` and `.bak`.

#### Counting the number of lines changed

This writes every changed line to stderr and then uses `wc` to count them:

```
sed -i 's:a:b:g; tc; b; :c; w /dev/stderr' file 2>&1 | wc -l
```

How it works:

- `s:a:b:g;`

  This is your substitute command
- `tc;`

  If a substitution was made, jump to label `c`.
- `b;`

  Branch to the end (after which sed will start fresh on the next line).  This line is only executed if not substitution was made.
- `:c;`

  This the label `c`.
- `w /dev/stderr`

  Write the line to stderr.
- `2>&1`

  Redirect stderr to stdout so that we can pipe it to `wc` for counting.

Comment: sed always changes the file date, even when no changes are made. I deleted my answer using find and upvoted this one.